# Sorting values with the same index in a data frame by column value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I am trying to arrange rows in a data frame first by index in ascending order, yet I I have rows with duplicate indexes. For these, I want them to be arranged in ascending order by their value in a specific column. Below is what my data frame looks like:

```
           layer   row   col       stage  conductance   riverbott
row_Index                                                        
8            0.0   8.0  29.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
6            0.0   6.0  21.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
7            0.0   7.0  22.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  24.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  14.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
12            0.0   8.0  53.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  23.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  12.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
```

I have tried doing

```
df = df.sort_values(['col'])
df = df.sort_index()
```

In my data frame, my index value is equal to my value in 'row'. I have tried using `df = df.sort_values(['row'])` instead of `df.sort_index()`. However, I keeping running into issues where my data frame is  first sorted by index in ascending order (this is desired), yet rows with duplicate indexes are arranged sometimes with the lowest column value coming first, and others with the highest column value coming first. For example:

```
           layer   row   col       stage  conductance   riverbott
row_Index                                                        
6            0.0   6.0  21.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
7            0.0   7.0  22.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  23.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  24.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  29.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  14.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  12.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
12            0.0   8.0  53.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
```

I would like my data frame to be organized like so:

```
           layer   row   col       stage  conductance   riverbott
row_Index                                                        
6            0.0   6.0  21.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
7            0.0   7.0  22.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  23.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  24.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0   8.0  29.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  12.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10            0.0   8.0  14.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
12            0.0   8.0  53.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
```

The reason I am doing this is because I want to remove duplicate indexes, keeping the one with the lowest value in 'col'.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort:

```py
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['row_Index', 'col']).set_index('row_Index')
```

**Output:**

```
           layer  row   col       stage  conductance   riverbott
row_Index                                                       
6            0.0  6.0  21.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
7            0.0  7.0  22.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0  8.0  23.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0  8.0  24.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
8            0.0  8.0  29.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10           0.0  8.0  12.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
10           0.0  8.0  14.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
12           0.0  8.0  53.0  123.170732    1250000.0  122.170732
```

Then to remove duplicates:

```py
df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: `sort_values` accepts Index names as well as column names, so just `df = df.sort_values(['row_Index', 'col'])`